# Request for member "duree" in something not a structure or union in scanf for integer

Tags: c

I'm getting the following error:

```
Request for member "duree" in something not a structure or union
```

On `scanf("%d",&var->duree)`.

`var` is a pointer to a structure.

Whenever there's an integer to read, the same error appears.

Can someone help me fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "structure_film.h"
#include<stdlib.h>

void ajouter_un_seul_film(struct film **var)
{ 
    int genre;

    if (*var==NULL)
    {
         printf("Espace insuffisant \n");
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Quel est le nom du film que vous voulez ajouter ? \n");
         scanf("%s",(*var)->nom);

         printf("\nCombien de minutes dure ce film ? \n");
         scanf("%d",&var->duree);

         printf("\nVeuillez entrez le numero de reference de ce film : \n");
         scanf("%d",&var->id);

         printf("\nQuel est l'annee de sortie? \n");
         scanf("%d",&var->dateSortie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
scanf("%d",&var->duree);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&( *var )->duree);
```

Comment: @user3136456: Welcome to SO! Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page some time, as your status suggests you have not yet done so. If an answer is to your liking, consider formally [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which is preferred over a comment "thanks".